# How to negate a bit column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I update a table column in order to revert its value(set true if value is false and false for true! null remains null).

Please exclude solutions where one uses `case when` or `IIF()` I want something like following

```
UPDATE mytable SET IsEditable = !IsEditable
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [bitwise NOT operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468.aspx):

```
update mytable set IsEditable = ~IsEditable
```

Comment: Well as fast as the bitwise or. :-D

Answer (score 23):

Just use this:

```sql
UPDATE mytable SET IsEditable=IsEditable^1
```

If you want to test it:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(bit,0)^1, CONVERT(bit,1)^1
```

Comment: This is good but I thing is slower since it is using bitwise `xor`! anyway, voted up

Comment: Well I've tested it with 1.000.000.000 rows in a fast test. Both produce the same time and consumes the same cpu (`STATISTICS TIME ON`). Well don't think that there is a real difference. :-)

Comment: sorry ! didn't test but as per definition `C=A^B=(A&(~B))|(B&(~A))` which seems slower than `C=~C` but I think by `xor`ing to `B` and `B` being equals to `1` there're no speed issue. Thank you @Ionic

Comment: Well no problem. :-) Nice that it helped.

Comment: Didn't mean to impose any style,  I was just trying to reduce them to the one.

Comment: I know. I just edited it to match it. :-) I normally prefer upper cased functions, for a faster/better reading. I know that you just wanted to match them. :-)

Answer (score 17):

As a math solution, you can use this

```
update mytable set IsEditable = 1 - IsEditable;
```

- `IsEditable = 0`    => `1 - IsEditable = 1`
- `IsEditable = 1`    => `1 - IsEditable = 0`
- `IsEditable = Null` => `1 - IsEditable = Null`

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/86412)

Comment: Could not upvote twice this! But it works perfectly thank you @shA.t

Comment: So simple and nice! This should be the accepted answer